# Opposite of ~~ in Perl

Tags: perl

Is there an opposite for the operator `~~` in Perl? I used it to match an element in an array like this:

```
my @arr = qw /hello ma duhs udsyyd hjgdsh/;
print "is in\n" if ('duhs' ~~ @arr);
```

This prints `is in`. It is pretty cool, because I don't have to iterate all the array and compare each record. My problem is that I want to do something if I don't have a match. I could go on the `else` side but I rather find a opposite for `~~'

Comment: The smartmatch operator is experimental, and likely to be removed or changed significantly. You probably shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

unless == if not

```
print "is not in\n" unless ('duhs' ~~ @arr);
```

Note: Smart matching is experimental in perl 5.18+. See [Smart matching is experimental/depreciated in 5.18 - recommendations?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1039456) So use the following instead:

```
print "is not in\n" unless grep { $_ eq 'duhs' } @arr;
```

Comment: `grep` has the disadvantage that it checks *all* of the list elements, even after a match has been found. Look at @Leeft's answer for a more efficient option.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util%20List::Util) (newer versions of this module only) or [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils%20List::MoreUtils) with `any`, `none` and friends.

```
use List::Util qw(any none);
my @arr = qw /hello ma duhs udsyyd hjgdsh/;
say "oh hi" if any { $_ eq 'hello' } @arr;
say "no goodbyes?" if none { $_ eq 'goodbye' } @arr;
```

While not perl-native, it doesn't need the experimental smartmatching.

Comment: This is the most correct answer. +1 `List::Util` is Perl-native in the sense that it is a core module.

Comment: @Borodin Correct, but it isn't until `List::Util` 1.33 (released 13th Oct 2013) that it includes these functions, and I'm not sure which Perl version includes 1.33+ out of the box. Our Perl installations at `$work` use modules a couple of years old, and thus `List::MoreUtils` is a much better approach for us (and probably many others) for the time being.

Comment: `corelist -a List::Util` seems to think that 5.19.4 included 1.32 while 5.19.5 used 1.35.  So 5.20.0 is (currently) the only stable version to have that functionality out of the box.